# cudart64_110.dll present but not found

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed checked and installed CUDA-v11.0 and the appropriate version of cudnn too!
when I just run *cudart64_110.dll* anywhere for my cmd
[I can that the file is indeed getting recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3cTa.png)

but, when I try to run TensorFlow, the system is not able to recognize cudart64_110.dll
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B93Dc.png)

Im trying all this on a AMD Ryzen 7, RTX 2060 laptop(ASUS TUF fx505DV)

Comment: You probably did not set the right paths for the library to be recognized globally

Comment: You restarted your shell, both screenshots have the same user permissions (i.e. admin), and it shows in your %PATH%? Also, what settings did you select in the Cuda installer? Looks like your CUDA versions match (v11).